# Android 2.2.3 gradle sync issue

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I update recently my android studio and I can´t either create a new project nor import an existing project, I always get an error when the sync started at the very beginning, let me paste you the error:

[image]

I pasted the error i got after I changed the version:

[image]

Comment: what is error you are getting?'

Comment: yo are not seeing the image I add?

Comment: sorry my bad, I just add the image

Answer (score 0):

May be current gradle version is not stable
add this stable gradle instead of updated one in project level gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

then sync .use online mode for syncing.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, I already change the version and now I'm recieving a new error. Just pasted on the description

Comment: new error is not replated to gradle build...seems like u r using internet permisson...there could me many reason of this error.check your key or link u rtrying to connect

Comment: were can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys it was a problem with the ssl becouse I´m using android studio in the office and we have a proxy, so I add it in the proxy configuration and it´s working just fine, thank you all!